# htaccess rewrite to new domain with passing all parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I found on google many suggestions and I tried to paste everything I need together. However, I did not manage my htaccess file to work.

I want to redirect everything from

```
www.gugus.com/abc/?lang=fr&something=true
```

to

```
https://test.example.com/abc/?lang=fr%something=true
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This htaccess must be at the `gugus.com` root :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ https://test.example.com/abc/ [L,R=301,QSA]
```

This will only redirect pages `abc` and `abc/`, with or without a query string.

**EDIT**

If you want the htaccess to be located into `abc/` folder :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://test.example.com/abc/ [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Is there a solution where the .htaccess file is in the /abc/ directory?

Comment: It's possible, see my edit. This won't redirect sub-pages like `gugus.com/abc/otherstuff.html`. If you wan't redirect all the traffic in `abc/` folder, use `^.*$` instead of `^/?$`

Comment: the redirected link does not contain any parameters. Is there a way to echo the new link? I do not know if something is wrong with passing the parameters and the application (behind the new url) replaces the current link with no parameters

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/abc` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gugus\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://test.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: With your solution I lose the query strings in url. I probably need somehow to be able to echo the new link in order to find out where the mistake is (htaccess or the application behind the new url)

Comment: Your solution works too. zessx was a bit quicker in answering the question. Therefore I accepted his solution. Thank you very much for your help!